# NSUserDefault not saving in simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults

No matter what I do, I cannot get my NSUserDefaults to save when using the iOS simulator. I've read the posts, and I am calling `synchronize`, but it's still not working.

I have a button that simulates a check box. When the button is clicked, the method `toggleSavedPassword` fires. Even after checking the box (i.e. setting "save_password" to true), when I come back into the app, the value is reset to false every time.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

This is my output every time I follow the sequence of launching the app and clicking the checkbox:

```
password NOT saved
user save password set to: true
password save set
user default didn't save
```

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];

    NSLog([self.userDefaults boolForKey:@"save_password"] ? @"password saved" : @"password NOT saved");

    // check the save password box based on user default settings
    if ([userDefaults boolForKey:@"save_password"]) {
        [self.savePasswordCheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}

- (IBAction)toggleSavePassword:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.savePassword = !self.savePassword;

    NSString *temp;
    if (self.savePassword) temp = @"true";
    else temp = @"false";
    NSLog(@"user save password set to: %@\n", temp);

    if (self.savePassword) {
        [self.savePasswordCheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"save_password"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        NSLog(@"password save set");

    } else {
        [self.savePasswordCheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.userDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"save_password"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    NSLog([self.userDefaults boolForKey:@"save_password"] ? @"Confirmed" : @"user default didn't save");

}
```

Comment: Why are you allocating NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init]; use [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] instead in viewDidLoad and then try

Comment: @San - I changed this. Still have the same problem and output.  @Michael Dauterman - I added that line at the end of my `toggleSavedPassword` method. All it did was appended another output that tells me `password NOT saved`

Comment: @usr55410 If you have changed, please update your question.

Comment: Someone just posted an answer that worked, but then they deleted their answer!??  The solution was to change the initialization to `self.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];` Free SO points to who ever suggests that answer first, I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is your  `self.userDefaults` `-setter` method 
BTW， it should be `NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

Answer (score 2):

No need to add the NSUserDefaults as a property.

You could just use

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

For saving:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"save_password"];
```

For retrieving:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"save_password"];
```

Comment: Thanks. It just makes for a little less code by setting the property. Ultimately, I'm going to wind up with quite a few of these preferences, so less code is a good thing. +1